# ASP.NET: Showing 'system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist' instead of actual Dropdown list in DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am fetching data from lists and populating it in DataTable row by row. In the last column, I want to show Dropdown list. But it is showing 'system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist' instead of actual dropdown list.
I also tried to add dropdownlist in cell and then adding cell in row, but it showed 'system.web.ui.WebControls.TableCell'.
Here is the code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < List.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
    r[0] = ParentList[0][i].ToString();
    string fiveSampleData = "";

    for (int j = 1; j <= numberOfRecordsToShow; j++)
    {
        fiveSampleData += ParentList[j][i].ToString() + " , ";
    }
    r[1] = fiveSampleData.ToString();

    DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
    ddl.ID = "row" + i;
    ddl.DataSource = StandardArray;
    ddl.DataBind();
    r[2] = ddl;        // Populating third column with Dropdown list
    dt.Rows.Add(r);
}
```

Comment: You should not mix up your presentation layer with your business logic or other layers. A DataRow is usually holding primitive objects like strings, numbers or Dates.
You oculd potentially populate a DropdownList with a datatable. But storing a ddl in a datatable is not something I think is possible.

Comment: Ok, sounds good.

Comment: If you want to display complex data in your html, I would not use a data table if you can use a `List<T>`. But without knowing if you use webforms or mvc or web api I do not think your problem is solveable, because we do not know what you want to use that datatable for.
My recommendation would be to create a view model class and store your data in a List.

Comment: Yes, that would be better.